# Need to format a dateTime object with a three character month

Tags: xslt

Here's my xslt statement:

```
<xsl:value-of select="format-dateTime(current-dateTime(), '[D01]-[MN, *-3]-[Y0001] [H01]:[m01]:[s01]')"/>
```

This is producing:

"05-FEBRUARY-2013 09:40:09"

This is almost what I want.  I need to restrict the month to three characters though (i.e., "FEB").

Comment: My coding statement isn't showing above.  The part in question of the formatting is three character month that I was trying to insert as "[MN, *-3]".  The other formatting statements are producing the desired results.  I just need "FEBRUARY" trimmed to "FEB".

Comment: You just need to edit your question and put four spaces in the front of that line. It will show up then.

Comment: No problem. I would have done it myself but I don't have enough rep to make that type of edit. Hopefully people can answer your question now.

Comment: What processor are you using? It worked for me with Saxon 9.4.0.4

Comment: I am using xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0".

Comment: Maybe a better word would be transformer. Like what program are you running the xslt in? There aren't that many 2.0 transformers so it must be Saxon or Altova and I think there is one or two others.

Comment: It is Altova XML Spy 2012.

Comment: Have you tried playing around with your format string. I don't know to what level Altova supports the standard. Try things like `[MN,*-3]`, and `[MN,1-3]`

Comment: Yes, I've tried several different ways, but to no avail.  I'm using this .xslt in a bpel component in a SOA suite and it seems to work there.  I'm not sure why Altova isn't handling it correctly.

Comment: I don't know what else to say, except to maybe contact Altova for support.

Comment: This post was really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

remove the space in "[MN, *-3]"

I had similar issue with this and that fixed it.